# Get current position in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am new to Ionic 2 and following some tutorials.

In this case I need to change following method:

```
 applyHaversine(locations){

        let usersLocation = {


            lat: 40.713744, 
            lng: -74.009056
        };

        locations.map((location) => {

            let placeLocation = {
                lat: location.latitude,
                lng: location.longitude
            };

            location.distance = this.getDistanceBetweenPoints(
                usersLocation,
                placeLocation,
                'miles'
            ).toFixed(2);
        });

        return locations;
    }
```

You can see that variable usersLocation is hard-coded:

```
let usersLocation = {


            lat: 40.713744, 
            lng: -74.009056
        };
```

I would like to get there the real user location.

I have seen the method Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(), but I don´t know how to implement it in this case.

Thank you

EDITED

```
 applyHaversine(locations){
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {

        let  latitud = resp.coords.latitude
        let longitud = resp.coords.longitude
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error getting location', error);
        });

  console.log(this.latitud);
        let usersLocation = {

           lat:  this.latitud, 
           lng:  this.longitud 
        };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the Geolocation cordova plugin. You can access it with `ionic-native`. First you need to install the plugin:

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --save
```

You can then use it like this:

```
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';

Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(res => {
  // res.coords.latitude
  // res.coords.longitude
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
});
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/geolocation/

EDIT:

Your updated code is almost correct. You made 2 small mistakes in your code:

1. You defined 2 local variables (`let latitud` and `let longitud`), but then later in your code you access them by using `this.latitud`and `this.longitud`. `this` always refers to variables defined in your class, so those will be undefined. You either have to use local variables or class wide variables, but that depends on your architecture. Both work.
2. `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` returns a promise. This means that the code inside `.then(() => {})` will be executed later (as soon as the plugin has the result with your location). But the rest of your code is outside the `then`, which means that it will be executed before you have the location. So you need to copy your whole code into the `then` like this:

   ```
   applyHaversine(locations) {
     Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(res => {
       let usersLocation = {
         lat: res.coords.latitude, 
         lng: res.coords.longitude
       };

       locations.map((location) => {

         let placeLocation = {
           lat: location.latitude,
           lng: location.longitude
         };

         location.distance = this.getDistanceBetweenPoints(
           usersLocation,
           placeLocation,
           'miles'
         ).toFixed(2);
       });

     console.log(locations); // This will now have your updated distances

     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('Error getting location', error);
     });

     return locations; // this will not work because the code above is asynchronous
   }
   ```

EDIT 2:

A working example would be:

```
applyHaversine(locations) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(res => {
      let usersLocation = {
        lat: res.coords.latitude, 
        lng: res.coords.longitude
      };

      locations.map((location) => {

        let placeLocation = {
          lat: location.latitude,
          lng: location.longitude
        };

        location.distance = this.getDistanceBetweenPoints(
          usersLocation,
          placeLocation,
          'miles'
        ).toFixed(2);
      });

    resolve(locations); // As soon as this is called, the "then" in will be executed in the function below.

    }).catch(reject);
  });
}
```

And where you use this function:

```
doSomething(locations) {
  this.applyHaversine(locations).then(res => {
    // The logic after you have your new results goes here.
    console.log(res); // res will be the value that you passed into the resolve function above, in this case your updated locations array
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas, but how do I get the coordinates from inside the let usersLocation {} variable definition?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. You can access the coordinates by writing `usersLocation.lat` and `usersLocation.lng`

Comment: I mean, where should I include your proposal, and how can I access the coordinates: res.coords.latitude and res.coords.longitude, from inside the let usersLocation {}...? I have included a proposal as EDITED in my question, but doesn´t work.

Comment: As I noted in my sample above, `return locations;` at the end won't work right now (it will be the same array you passed to the function). What do you want to do with the data after you finish your calculations?
There are 2 ways to solve this issue:
1. Save it in a class property
2. Return another promise

You should probably read about Promises and asynchronous code in Javascript to understand those issues.

Comment: As it is now, I am getting a list of positions that are shown on a google maps map.

Comment: I guess I have to learn a lot for the moment, thank you in any case.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer with a *hopefully* working example. If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask. But it is probably best if you read about the basics of callbacks and promises first.