# parsing coordinate value to number - Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

how I can pass the value from current coordinate
this my code

```
applyHaversine(locations){

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
        this.myLat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.myLng = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(this.myLat+" <==> "+this.myLng);
    });

    let usersLocation = {
        lat: this.myLat,
        lng: this.myLng
    };

    locations.map((location) => {

        let placeLocation = {
            lat: location.latitude,
            lng: location.longitude
        };

        location.distance = this.getDistanceBetweenPoints(
            usersLocation,
            placeLocation,
            'miles'
        ).toFixed(2);
    });

    return locations;
}
```

I want dynamics value from current locations
if I use static value it will be:

```
let usersLocation = { 
        lat: 3.9764484, //static data
        lng: 122.5089854 //static data
    };
```

Comment: Where are you using `usersLocation`? Where do you want to display `myLat` and `MyLng`?

Comment: i want to calculate the distance use haversine formula,, my full function ('http://pastebin.com/EgYFSwK4')

Comment: i just want print lat and lng value into console.log, i need number value

Comment: Link is not working, can you paste the code by editing your question?

Comment: But you are already logging it with `console.log(this.myLat+" <==> "+this.myLng);`

Comment: i edited,, in 'console.log();' it print object data, not number of coordinat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132570/discussion-between-rizaldy-setiawan-h-and-echonax).

Answer (score 0):

The `getCurrentPosition` function is asynchronous and returns a promise. This means the code inside the `then(...)` will be executed after the other code has already finished, which means that `this.myLat` and `this.myLng` will be undefined.

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
    this.myLat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.myLng = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log(this.myLat+" <==> "+this.myLng);
});
```

This means you need to adjust your code to be able to handle this asynchronous call. The best way would be to use promises.

Someone asked the exact same question a couple of weeks ago and I gave him a detailed answer with an example. You can find it here: [Get current position in ionic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206663/get-current-position-in-ionic2/41213056#41213056)