# I get undefined when using "position.coords.latitude" to trying to get the current poistion

Tags: google-maps, typescript, geolocation, ionic2

I'm new to Ionic2, I've followed this tutorial and it worked perfectly https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-nearby-places-list-with-google-maps-in-ionic-2-part-1/, it lists some places and then calculates the distance between these places and a place given hard-coded, what I wanted to achieve is using the current place instead of the one given in code, here's the screenshot of what I achieved so far [screenshot of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEy3R.png)
and here is my locations provider :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Geolocation} from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

/*
  Generated class for the LocationsProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class LocationsProvider {

    data: any;
    Currentlatitude: any;
    Currentlongitude: any;
   

    constructor(public http: Http, public geolocation: Geolocation) {
        console.log('Hello LocationsProvider Provider'); 
    }

    load(){     
        this.geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe((position) => {
            this.Currentlatitude = position.coords.latitude;
            this.Currentlongitude = position.coords.longitude;                 
        });

        if(this.data){
            return Promise.resolve(this.data);
        }
 
        return new Promise(resolve => {     
            this.http.get('assets/data/locations.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {     
                this.data = this.applyHaversine(data.locations);     
                this.data.sort((locationA, locationB) => {
                    return locationA.distance - locationB.distance;
                });     
                resolve(this.data);
            });     
        });     
    }
 
    applyHaversine(locations){
    // this must change according to the device location
    /*

        let usersLocation = {
            lat: 40.713744, 
            lng: -74.009056
        };  */

        console.log("this.Currentlatitude ",this.Currentlatitude);
 
        let usersLocation = {
            latitude: this.Currentlatitude,
            longitude: this.Currentlongitude
        };

        console.log("usersLocation.latitude ",usersLocation.latitude);
        locations.map((location) => {
            let placeLocation = {
                latitude: location.latitude,
                longitude: location.longitude
            };

            location.distance = this.getDistanceBetweenPoints(usersLocation, placeLocation, 'km').toFixed(2);               
        });

        return locations;
    }
 
    getDistanceBetweenPoints(start, end, units){     
        let earthRadius = {
            miles: 3958.8,
            km: 6371
        };
 
        let R = earthRadius[units || 'km'];
         
        let lat1 = start.latitude;
        
        let lon1 = start.longitude;
      
        let lat2 = end.latitude;
         
        let lon2 = end.longitude;
        console.log("lon1 ",lat1); // here it gives me undefined

        let dLat = this.toRad((lat2 - lat1));
         
        let dLon = this.toRad((lon2 - lon1));
         
        let a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(this.toRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(this.toRad(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLon / 2) *
        Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        
        let c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        let d = R * c;
         
        return d;     
    }
 
    toRad(x){            
        return x * Math.PI / 180;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured things out, my problem was that I didn't understand synchronous and asynchronous tasks while working with Promises and Observables in Ionic, for the ones who have the same problem, I suggest this tutorial that explains that https://www.joshmorony.com/dealing-with-asynchronous-code-in-ionic/ .
As for the solution of my program I found a solution in this question [Get current position in ionic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206663/get-current-position-in-ionic2)

Answer (score 0):

I made a location service for my application recently. I use the geolocation plugin to get my current location and the [distancematrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/) api from google maps to get the distance/time between to addresses (coordinates or normal addresses)

```
import { Query } from '../models/query';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Geolocation, Geoposition, Coordinates } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { NativeGeocoder, NativeGeocoderReverseResult, NativeGeocoderForwardResult } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder';

@Injectable()
export class LocationService {

  google_API_KEY: string = 'API_KEY_FROM_GOOGLE_GOES_HERE';
  currentLocation: Geoposition;

  constructor(public http: Http, private geolocation: Geolocation,
    private geocoder: NativeGeocoder) {
    // Set your current location here, or remove this and set it manually throughout the app
    this.setCurrentLocation();
  }


  setCurrentLocation() {
    return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      // Manipulate resp here if needed
      this.currentLocation = resp;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.currentLocation));
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    })
  }

  getBetweenCoordsDetails(fromString: string, toString: string) {
    let query = new Query('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json');
    query.add('key', this.google_API_KEY);
    query.add('destinations', toString);
    query.add('origins', fromString);
    query.add('units', 'imperial');
    return this.http.get(query.toQuery())
      .do(resp => {
        let x = resp;
      }, error => {
        let x = error;
      })

  }

  getBetweenCoordAndHereDetails(toString: string) {
    let x = this.currentLocation.coords;
    return this.getBetweenCoordsDetails(this.currentLocation.coords.latitude + ',' + this.currentLocation.coords.longitude, toString);
  }

  getCoordinatesFromAddress(address: string) {
    return this.geocoder.forwardGeocode(address);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll test that and then mark your answer . my greetings

Comment: I noticed that you are using a model called "Query" can you provide me with example code, I much appreciate