# Ionic 2 Geolocation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm new to Ionic and I'm currently learning. I tried to implement Geolocation plugin in app.component.ts on platform.ready function and I get lat and lng, but how can I send lat and lng to home page to display current location on a map. Should I implement geolocation function in provider?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206663/get-current-position-in-ionic2

Answer (score 0):

you can use ionic providers .

```
ionic g provider map
```

then write the code which wrote in app.component.ts there. and implement a getfunction like

```
getLatLng(){
return {lat:this.lat,lng:this.lng}
}
```

then import the provider into your home page and call the getLatLng() method.

Please research about ionic services/providers and Promises and observables. you can use these handy

Comment: Thanks. And how can I return lat and lng in local variable to use it in other function?

Comment: you can call your provider method .  var latlng =this.myprovider.getLatLng();